# Failed to start Jenkins on macOs - Java 10

Tags: java, macos, jenkins, java-10

I'm trying to start Jenkins using:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

I got this error:

> ```
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 54.0
> at Main.main(Main.java:128)
> ```

This problem comes after an update of my development environment, I'd switched to :

- Java 10.0.1+10
- Jenkins 2.107.2
- MacOS 10.13.4

Comment: Is this version of Jenkins compatible with JDK10?

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek, How can i check this ?

Comment: ([Just in case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52080060/1746118)) The version above 2.127 currently available as weekly release are compatible with Java10. @GrzegorzPiwowarek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error message that you are getting:

- The JAR / WAR file being loaded was compiled for Java 10 (and later) because the message says that the classfile version is 54.
- The JRE that is actually being used is Java 9 or earlier.  If you were using Java 10, it would be happy with version 54.

In other words, despite upgrading your Java to Java 10, you must be *using* an older version to start Jenkins.

Check the launch script for Jenkins and make sure that it uses the correct JRE installation.

If you are launching Jenkins using `java -jar jenkins.war`, check what `java -version` tells you ... at the same command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach could be to download ***Jenkins WAR for 2.127*** (weekly release) or above. Then one can run the war with the following command:

```
${JAVA10_HOME}/bin/java --add-modules java.xml.bind -jar jenkins.war \
--enable-future-java --httpPort=8080 --prefix=/jenkins
```

---

Though note that there are few known issues registered on their tracker :

- Pipeline crashes immediately on Java 10 and 11 ([JENKINS-46602](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46602))
- There are many warnings about Illegal reflective access during execution ([JENKINS-40689](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40689))
- Configuration-as-Code plugin fails to export configurations on Java 10 ([JENKINS-51991](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51991))

---

Here are the individual tracker for [Java 10 compatiblity](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40689) and [one for Java 11](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51805).

***Source*** - **[Jenkins with Java10-11](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/06/17/running-jenkins-with-java10-11/)**