# How to configure to run jenkins with java 10 on mac?

Tags: java, macos, jenkins, osx-lion, java-10

I have java 10 installed on mac os.
Installed jenkins.
While trying to launch jenkins by following command

```
java -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
```

Getting following error

```
Jenkins requires Java 8, but you are running 10.0.1+10 from 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 54.0
   at Main.main(Main.java:128)
```

Comment: Both of the duplicate questions did not answer the question which I have posted here. This question is about how to configure jenkins with JAVA 10 and not to degrade the java version.

Comment: you might just want to [upgrade the Jenkins version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52080060/1746118) probably in that case?

Comment: I have installed the latest version downloaded from jenkins website https://jenkins.io/download/. Version: Jenkins LTS 2.121.3

Comment: Since the one mentioned in the answer is a weekly release. I would guess the [LTS for Java10](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52284), still being open could be one of the signs of incompatibility between Java10 and Jenkins. The overall problem you've listed out is more based on the other duplicate link(UnsupportedClassVersion) as shared anyhow.

Comment: All right. Thanks.

Comment: The official answer is not covered by either of the supposed duplicates; it’s “No.”  https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/ : 
“Java 8 is the ONLY currently supported runtime environment… Java 9 and Java 10 are not supported.  
Java 11 preview support is available”